# How to print all cookies in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I have written some code in node.js to get the cookies for my route.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
var cookies = req.cookies;
res.render('cartoons', {
    Cookies: cookies,
  });
});
```

My cartoons Jade file looks like:

```
h1 cartoons
 p Cookies for this page =
 b #{Cookies}
```

I am able to see all cookies like "{ cartoons_: '1', toys_: '1' }" in console if i print them. But on webpage, i am not able to see the values getting output like:

**Cookies for this page = [Object Object]**

I don't know what is going wrong. Could someone help me in getting these values displayed on my webpage.

Comment: just use `var cookies = JSON.stringify(req.cookies);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your view engine for Jade is rendering the `Cookies` variable it is calling `.toString()` on that variable. On an Object, `.toString()` returns `[object Object]` which, is what you are seeing injected into your html. The way to see an object, as you would in the console, is to use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). It traverses whatever JS object is passed into it and creates a valid JSON string representation of that JS object. Since this is a string, it can be passed directly to `res.render()` for injection into the view tempate.

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let Cookies = JSON.stringify(req.cookies)

  return res.render('cartoons', {Cookies})
})
```